# Leaflet Get Bounds w/ only top padding

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am aware of the [pad](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#latlngbounds-pad) method when calling `getBounds()`, but is there a way I can specify padding ONLY on the top of the map?

For example, this pads all side equally:

```js
const box = map.getBounds().pad(-.2).toBBoxString()
```

I am basically looking to do in Leaflet what Mapbox does [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#paddingoptions).

Answer (score 1):

Just spitballing.

```
# Expand the northern boundary (and the others) to the correct size
tmp_expanded = map.getBounds().pad( -0.2 );
# Get a coordinate along the northern boundary
northern_coord = tmp_expanded.getNorthEast();
# Expand the northern boundary only by encompassing the northern coord
box = map.getBounds().extend( northern_coord ).toBBoxString();
```

It's not pretty, but it may do the trick.